# Cordova - Install AdMob Plugin on Android Failed (Mac)

Tags: android, git, cordova, plugins, admob

I am facing thi error in installing AdMob cordova plugin on android https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob ,, The plugin is installed and works fine with iOS platform, but it gives this error on android.

**My Enviroment:**

- Cordova 3.5
- Android api 19
- Java 8
- Eclipse Luna
- Apache Ant 1.9.4
- npm 1.4.16

  Command:

  cordova plugin add https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob.git

> Fetching plugin
>   "https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob.git" via git
>   clone
>       Installing "com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.admob" for android
>       Fetching plugin "com.google.admobsdk" via plugin registry
>       Installing "com.google.admobsdk" for android
>       Fetching plugin "com.google.playservices@19.0.0" via plugin registry
>       **Failed to install 'com.google.admobsdk':Error: Expected fetched plugin to have ID "com.google.playservices@19.0.0" but got
>   "com.google.playservices"**.
>           at checkID (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:116:19)
>           at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:99:24
>           at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
>           at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
>           at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
>           at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
>           at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
>           at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
>       Failed to install 'com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.admob':Error: Expected fetched plugin to have ID "com.google.playservices@19.0.0" but got
>   "com.google.playservices".
>           at checkID (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:116:19)
>           at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:99:24
>           at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
>           at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
>           at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
>           at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
>           at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
>           at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
>       Error: Expected fetched plugin to have ID "com.google.playservices@19.0.0" but got "com.google.playservices".
>           at checkID (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:116:19)
>           at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:99:24
>           at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
>           at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
>           at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
>           at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
>           at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
>           at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)

Any ideas?!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The simple answer is:

You need upgrade to cordova CLI v4.0, just run:

```
sudo npm install cordova -g
```

## The detailed answer is:

The root cause of this failure is, cordova CLI v3.5 does not correctly recognize the following dependency in plugin `com.google.admobsdk`.

```
<dependency id="com.google.playservices@19.0.0"/>
```

You may ask, why `@19.0.0` is added?

It's used to specify an exact version, and keep it compatible with cordova CLI and Intel XDK.

As the default `com.google.playservices` (@21.0.0) cannot be handled by Intel XDK (at least so far, when this answer is being posted), while version `com.google.playservices@19.0.0` can be correctly handled by Intel XDK.

Some bugs in cordova v3.5 causes this problem and has been fixed in cordova v4.0, mentioned as "Pinned dependencies" in the release notes.

See release notes: http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/10/16/cordova-4.html

So, please upgrade to cordova CLI v4.0, it will be much easier.

If any issue, please ask in the project issue tracker page, you will be supported timely.

Comment: Yes Indeed, that was my solution

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this one and works fine for me: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova

```
cordova plugin add cordova-admob
```

If you run in phonegap build, then:

```
<gap:plugin name="phonegap-admob" source="npm"/>
```